Parsing bold text to telegram with python
I'm trying to send some bold text to my telegram channel using python but so far Ive been unsucessful and was looking for some help to do it
I was using this function with MarkdownV2
def escape_markdown_v2(text):
    special_chars = r"_[]()~`>#+|{}.!"
    for char in special_chars:
        text = text.replace(char, f'\\{char}')
   return text

And this to create the message
def create_match_message(home_team, away_team, match_date, match_time, stadium, tv_channels):
    # Format the text with MarkdownV2 syntax for bold text (wrap in `*`)
    message = (
        f"*{home_team} vs {away_team}*\n"
        f"*Date:* {match_date}\n"
        f"*Time:* {match_time}\n"
        f"*Venue:* {stadium}\n"
        f"*TV Channels:* {tv_channels}"
    )    
    escaped_message = escape_markdown_v2(message)
    return escaped_message

And finally this to send the message to tg
def send_telegram_message(group_id, topic_id, message):
    url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN}/sendMessage"
    payload = {
        "chat_id": group_id,
        "text": message,
        "reply_to_message_id": topic_id,
        "parse_mode": "MarkdownV2"  
    }
    response = requests.post(url, json=payload)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(f"Error sending message: {response.status_code}, Response: {response.text}")
    else:
        print("Message sent successfully!")

But unfortunately it outputs like this....
*Oxford Utd vs Hull*
*Date:* 2024-11-05
*Time:* 19:45:00
*Venue:* The Kassam Stadium
*TV Channels:* Sky Sports\+

Any help would be much appreciated.

@toyotaSupra From https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-markdown/info: "The Python Markdown is an extension for Jupyter Notebook that allows displaying output produced by the current kernel in markdown cells." - I think this question has nothing to do with that.

Don't escape the whole message, because that will force all of your markdown formatting to be treated as literal characters. You should only escape the variables that are inserted into the message template, since you cannot know in advance that they do not contain markdown special characters.

You need to escape your special characters in the message that you are sending via your payload.
Here is the style guide for MarkdownV2: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdownv2-style
Namely, you need to escape the slash in your newline character. You may also need to check your strings for characters that need to be escaped, as well.
For example, if I wanted to send Hello\nWelcome I would need to escape the slash character like this: Hello\\\nWelcome.
